# php bar graph array

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the below php script (from [Simple Horizontal Bar Graph using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968678/simple-horizontal-bar-graph-using-php)) to create a horizontal bar graph from and I'm dynamically replacing the static array values with database values which is working great except when there are duplicate values.  I need to allow duplicates numbers for the bar chart to be accurate - however due to the array, when there is a duplicate one of the "bars" goes missing.

Could I re-write this long hand without using an array and/or the foreach loop ?

```
$values = array(
        $values['one'] => 'apples',
        $values['two'] => 'oranges',
        $values['three'] => 'pears',
    $values['four'] => 'bananas'
);

// Find the maximum percentage
$max = max(array_keys($values));

foreach($values as $percentage => $label) {
// Calculate the position, maximum value gets position 0, smaller values approach 200
$pos = 200 - ($percentage / $max) * 200;
// Output the label that shows the percentage
echo '<span><label>'.$percentage.'%</label></span>';
// Output the span, apply style rule for the background position
echo '<span class="bar" style="background-position: -'.$pos.'px 0;">'.$label.'</span>';
}
?>
```

Comment: why do you have 'one','two','three' in your arrays? you can just do array('apples','oranges',...); and there aren't any other ways. foreach is the only way to get loops

Comment: regarding the loop - what I mean is why do I need an array or a loop - with only 4 items couldn't I write each one out - using variables or something like that ?

Comment: @Jung3o - `foreach` is not the only way to loop over an array. It's the best way, for sure, but not the only way.